# show jquery ajax execution status

Tags: php, cakephp, jquery

Let say I'm making an ajax call to some cakePHP controller action to delete some data from a database. But before I delete the data (which happens of course in my cakePHP controller action), I want to check whether or not the user who's requesting to delete the data has the permission to do so. What I'm trying to do is to display to the user the steps of executions, for example I have something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '.../some_cakePHP_controller_action',
    beforeSend: function(){
        $("my_loading_div").html("Checking permissions...");
    }
    success: function(){
        // do stuff on success
    }
});
```

1- When user clicks DELETE, I want to show him a loading div with a message like `Checking permissions...`

2- If the user has permissions to delete the data, the message changes for `Removing data...`

Now, as you can see above, the problem is that when the user clicks DELETE, he will have the message `Checking permissions....`, but my data may have been removed because I'm already inside my cakePHP function. So, the user will have the wrong message. How do I achieve this behavior please?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: for this you need to call $.ajax twice once for checking and then removing.or next $.ajax for both the steps.

Answer (score 3):

You need multiple ajax call for this. The steps will be something like this,

1. ajax call to check permission.
2. On php end check if you have delete permission with [is_writable](http://bd.php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php) function.
3. Return the status of previous step and show this as ajax response
4. According to the status of step 3. Send the delete request to php by ajax
5. Call [unlink](http://php.net/unlink) on php end. Then check again if the file exists by [file_exists](http://php.net/file_exists)
6. Return the status of previous step and show message to user accordingly

Comment: I thought I could do this in one Ajax call, I think I'm going to need 2 calls for this

Comment: @user765368 Yeah. Step 1 and Step 4

Answer (score 1):

You may probably wants to make 2 ajax calls. First to check the permission and if permission available then to delete the item.

```
$("statusDiv").html("Checking permissions").fadeIn(100,function(){

   $.post("checkpermission?item=23",function(data){

         if(data=="allowed")
         {
             $("#statusDiv").html("Deleting...");
             $.post("mycontroller/delete/23",function(result){
               if(result=="deleted")
               {
                  $("#statusDiv").html("Deleted Successfully");
               }
            });    
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not safe to validate if user is allowed or not via JS!!!
JS can be modified before clicking on "Delete".
You should validate it via PHP or both.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would check the permissions before giving them the option to delete something.  More than likely I would simply do this when the page is being rendered.  Something like:

```
<?php if (hasPermission) { ?> 
  html to show delete function 
<?php } else { ?> 
  html to login to delete
<?php } ?>
```